# Back tire flat only when I sit on it

Tags: tire, inflation

My back tire goes flat only when I sit on it or ride on it.  When I am not on it, the tire is fully blown up and feels the way it should.

It is squeaking too.

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  What size tyre is it, and what pressure do you have it inflated to?  It is extremely hard, and not recommended, to try and judge tyre pressure by feel.

Comment: how did you measure the pressure of the tire?

Answer (score 11):

A tire may look fully inflated when only the bike's weight is on it.

The median bike weight is somewhere between 10 and 15 kilograms, so about half of that on each wheel.

But add a rider who weighs somewhere between 50 and 100 kg and that's a 5-10x increase on each wheel.

Your tyre needs more air inside to support the loaded weight.   That number depends on the width of the tyre, but could be anything from 30 PSI to 80 PSI.

You can read the tyre's sidewall for some approximate maximum limits.

---

Squeaking could be the tread squirming on painted/coated concrete, or it could be the bead where the tyre and metal rim intersect.  Sometimes brand new tyres squeak because of the molding agent on the outside - that takes around 10 km of riding to wear through.

I'd suggest sorting the pressure, and the squeak may resolve itself.

Comment: +1 on the answer, I would just add in that it is worth checking how we got to the flat tire. It might just be an older bike that was in storage for weeks or month and needs re-inflation once for good measure but it could be a slow puncture if it reoccurs within hours or days.

Comment: @DoNuT first it's worth to just inflate the tyre and see if that fixes the issue. No point spending time pondering how the tyre got flat if it's not really flat at all but only happened to be underinflated.

Answer (score 9):

If you're used to wider tyres, you may be used to a certain level of firmness under pressure. Narrower tyres need to feel a lot harder. They will still have some give when you squeeze them with your thumb against your hand, but not much. A pressure gauge is a good idea to compare numbers against the range printed on the tyre, especially if you haven't got a feel for it yet.

Answer (score 7):

If the tyre becomes flat, i.e. the pressure that was actually there is lost, when you sit and ride on the tyre, it can mean that there is a puncture, that is impartially sealed by the object that penetrated the inner tube (or the tyre for a tubeless setup) and due to the deformation caused by your weight and rolling the tyre the impartial seal is opened and the air is released.

For example, I had punctures in a tubeless tyre, where the sealant managed to seal the largeish hole when the tyre was on an empty bike, but it did not hold it during a ride. I also had inner tube flats caused by thorns that took many hours to empty the tyre when it wasn't being ridden.

Comment: Good point - I presumed the tyre was squishing on the bottom but came back to shape when the rider dismounted.  Your point is that air might be forced out a small hole that otherwise would be sealed, and the rider's mass is enough to overcome that hole's seal.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to believe you 100% here. When you inflate the tire, it feels as hard as solid rubber, the way it should, but when you put weight on the bike, it goes flat. That could happen due to some inner tube or valve damage that is held closed by pressure, but opened when the rubber distorts. It's not unheard of for the speed of a slow leak to vary like this.

Bottom line is that there is a puncture or other damage; you have to pull the tire off the rim, examine the inner tube for punctures or other damage to determine whether to repair or replace, and examine the tire for lodged foreign objects, and all that.

The defect in the inner tube might be painfully obvious if you inflate it by itself, off the rim and out of the tire. When a leak is hard to find, you can put the inflated inner tube under water and watch for bubbles.

And that's basically the run-down on leaky tubes, exclusive of repair instructions.

Last words of advice: a detached valve, or damage around the valve stem base, is usually not reliably fixable. Large tears, ditto.  Have multiple inner tubes. Put a good tube on the wheel, and don't forget to fix the removed one soon then carry *that* one as your spare. I carry two spare tubes. I used to carry one, until one day I hit a simultaneous double flat. It happened on a highway, under an overpass, where extra amounts of crap accumulated on the road shoulder, due to having nowhere to go.

Comment: The other thing I learned to look for can be a cause of multiple inner tube punctures in the same place. I got through three new tubes before I found it: a fragment of a thorn barely penetrating through the cover, but projecting more when ridden. It was so small as to be invisible -- I found it by feel. It helps if you mark the relationship between cover, tube and inflator with chalk before removing and testing the tube. When you find the bubbles, you can match up the cover with the leak to find the culprit.

Comment: As an Electrical Engineer (EE), there are circuits where you measure the voltage (say of a battery) and it is fine, whereas if it is under a load, it cannot provide enough current.  Perhaps this is an 'analog' of what is going on with the bike.

Comment: @JosephDoggie In electronics, there can be intermittent circuits due to cold or cracked solder joints, oxidized or loose contacts and whatnot. A device appears to work until you slightly flex the circuit board, or bend a cable or whatever.